# Mount NFS share in docker in rootless mode

Tags: docker, containers, root, nfs, rootless

I am trying to mount an NFS share in a docker containe, but I cannot do so because the container running under rootlesskit does not have permissions to use escalate privileges on the host.

Is there a way to mount a share with rootlesskit or modify the rootlesskit somehow?